# How to manage images to decrease page load?

Tags: asp.net, image, pagespeed

I am requesting more then 30 images in my page.

The page load time is almost 25s.

How to decrease the load time.

Is there any method that will minimize the image size and download faster.

each image is 25KB and its taking almost 5.5s each image.

I have to show all the image in my page.

Comment: its showing blocking time is 4.77s how to decrease that one

Comment: what is your mean of blocking time?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2nl8fax&s=5  you can see in this image blocking time is showing

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what the other guys said, 
you can try using [CSS Image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). This will reduce the number of server requests and hence the load time of the page.

Just make sure you don't make the common mistake of using CSS Image sprite,

**The wrong way**

```
.element1 { background:url('img.jpg') 10px 10px no-repeat; }
.element2 { background:url('img.jpg') 20px 20px no-repeat; }

<div class="element1"></div>
<div class="element2"></div>
```

This will still make 2 different server requests for the same image.

**The right way**

```
.cssSprite {
    background:url('img.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.element1 { background-position: 10px 10px; }
.element2 { background-position: 20px 20px; }

<div class="cssSprite element1"></div>
<div class="cssSprite element2"></div>
```

This will create only 1 request to the server.

Comment: I think this method will not save even 1 second! since most of load time is on image size and not server request time!

Comment: So? css image sprites will reduce the *number* of server requests. While there's possibility that wrong use of this method may have the opposite effect, it's a perfectly good method to *try*, in addition to compressing the images.

Comment: Contrary to what @majidgeek said I think this is a perfectly good answer and might be a really good solution. He would have to analize the communication a little to be confident to say that "most of load time is on image size and not server request time". I think he is just making incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @SoonDead assume that we have 10*500KB images with 2Mb/s DSL,if you assume that each server response time be 200ms, then download time is 5000/256=~20s but 10*200=2s. if my assumption is wrong, please show correct assumption!

Answer (score 3):

Beside decreasing your image size there are some techniques that helps you to load your web pages faster. Please look at this:

[10 Quick Tips For Making Your Large Graphics Load Faster](http://resources.bravenet.com/articles/design/graphics/10_quick_tips_for_making_your_large_graphics_load_faster/)

And if it is possible you can use a separate server for your resources like images, animations, scripts and style sheets

Answer (score 0):

To decrease your images size and page load time you can compress images using softwares like JPEGCompressor or open source software like Gimp.